# Rename files numbered in reverse order in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a practical way to do this exercise in shell.

I have these files:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt [...] 50.txt
```

I want to rename this way

```
50.txt → 1.txt
49.txt → 2.txt
48.txt → 3.txt
...
```

Rename them in reverse order.

Comment: I tried with a loop but I was thinking something more simple.

Comment: Stackoverflow is really meant for specific problems in programming like "why am I getting 'missing destination file operand' in this program that tries to rename files in reverse order?". For open ended tasks like "please write me a program that renames files in reverse order in bash", you can get that cheaply with any of a number of online freelancing sites.

Comment: If you can supply your `loop`, then this question may actually have an answer.. or at least we can steer you in the right direction... FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RobinPlotnik not sure I understand your meaning..

Comment: @RobinPlotnik `continue` is an instruction that only has meaning inside a loop structure. Please edit your question to include the code you are using  and exact error messages you are  using. Otherwise you're asking everyone to play "20 questions" with you. Also I'd recommend that you only try to rename file1...3, to simplify your debugging. Good

Comment: @ptierno nevermind, some kind of joke I mean my loop is little dirty.

Comment: `n=1
r=50
while [ $n -le 50 ]; do

    mv $n.txt $r.txt
    let n++
    let r--
done`

Comment: @Robin this code will modify your first half files with next half files in reverse order and lead to 2 copy of each files in 2nd half, while 1st half files will be gone.

Comment: Also you need to first modify current file name with temporary name and than rename them to actual file name you want. Also this sort of code will work only with static data and pre-known file names ( assuming nothing is missing) and may be more constraints so need to be more cautious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directory `renamed` to prevent rewriting old files with new ones and try this code:

```
for i in {1..50}; do
    mv "$i.txt" "renamed/$(( 50 - $i + 1 )).txt"
done
```

This will reverse the file names.

Answer (score 2):

I use this script in bash that works with different numbering or even other naming formats:

```
#/bin/bash
#$1 - input folder, $2 output folder

INPUT_FILES=($(ls $1))
COUNT=$(ls $1 | wc -l)
COUNT_DEC=$((COUNT-1))
for i in $(seq 0 $COUNT_DEC); do
    ii=$((COUNT_DEC-i))
    echo "Copying: "$1"/"${INPUT_FILES[i]}" to "$2"/"${INPUT_FILES[ii]}
    cp $1/${INPUT_FILES[i]} $2/${INPUT_FILES[ii]}
done
```